# Insterting a new Row and Copy the data from a cell to it using Commands/code in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I never programmed an Excel macro using vba and I heard it can do nice things. I'm facing a problem I hope an Excel macro can solve for me, because I have huge amounts of data that need filtering. It's simple I will explain in an example

**Original Table:**

```
name1 123456789
name2 234567783 3456677889
name3 213123123
name4 123451231 123412312 1231223523
```

What macro need to do is when he finds data in the third column or forth or both he insert a new row and put the fill it with the name from the column and the number from the third column so data will be like that

**How table is supposed to be:**

```
name1 123456789 (stays the same no data in column 3 or 4)
name2 234567783 (removes the third column data and put it in a new row)
name2 3456677889 (keeping the name that the data had)
name3 213123123 (stays the same no data in column 3 or 4)
name4 123451231 (removes the third column data and forth column data and put it in new rows)
name4 123412312 
name4 1231223523
```

I tried to work on the script here's what I reached till now :

```
Sub test()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("d2:d40")
    If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        MyAddress = ActiveCell.Row
        Rows(MyAddress).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("a" & cell.Row).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("a" & cell.Row + 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("b" & "cell.Row").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Range("B" & cell.Row).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

After I execute this macro Excel freezes - any idea why ?

Comment: `i never programed an excel macro using vba and i heard it can do nice things` Yes it can :) Perhaps this is a good opportunity to start learning it and giving it a try? Post the code that you tried and where are you stuck and then we will take it from there? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: my code ? no no xD i didn't write a code i just tried to read how excel core works and i couldn't understand it :/

Comment: I know you don't have a code. And hence I suggested, learning VBA and trying the code and then posting it here if you get stuck :) No one will write the code for you... Well `almost` no one :P See the link that I posted in my first comment.

Comment: damn so i have to make it manually :/ okay thanks anyways! it was worth the try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code was this line, which kept expanding the range, so would never reach the end, hence the "freeze"

```
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Have a look at this code, which starts at the bottom of data, and works up, thus avoiding the problem of the ever-expanding range.  It assumes that your data starts at "A1".

```
Sub test2()

Dim r As Range, x As Long, y As Long, Cnt As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False '**faster

With ActiveSheet 'specify actual sheet
    Cnt = .Cells(.Rows.CountLarge, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last non blank cell in column A
'   rows loop
    For y = Cnt To 1 Step -1 'start at last row and work up
        Set r = .Range(.Cells(y, 1), .Cells(y, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) 'current row
'       loop thru cells in current row

        If Not IsEmpty(r(1)) Then '** skip empty cell

          For x = r.Cells.Count To 3 Step -1
             r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert row
             r(x).Cut r(2).Offset(1) 'number to column B
             r(1).Offset(1).Value = r(1).Value 'name to column A
         Next x
       End If '**
    Next y
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True '**

End Sub
```

Comment: Its working just great Thank you so much but i have a single problem! i added an if condition so if the cell is empty it doesn't make a new row and insert data in it but its not working i don't know why here what i did

'
           If Not IsEmpty(r.Cells.Value) Then

Comment: I've edited my code, see if that does it for you.  Also note lines setting ScreenUpdating to false/true, will speed things up.